# Fragment with custom ListView keeps throwing error inflating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ListView that I'm trying to turn into a Fragment inside a MainActivity. This used to work last week but apparently I made some change and now just makes it keep popping this error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment

By debugging I found out that the problem happens in the ListView creation line:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //  (more code)

    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.records_listview);

    //  (more code)

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

}
```

The xml file records_listview is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/records_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/records_btn_add"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am completely stunned since this used to work. ListView behaves properly if put inside an Activity. There are also buttons on this View, that's why I'm using Fragment and not ListFragment.

Comment: when ever you are inflating the layout then only you will the child views so try View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.records_listview);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getView()` method will return null in `onCreateView()`, as the `View` you return from that method is what gets set as the `Fragment`'s `View`. Change the method as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    ...
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.records_listview);
    ...
    return view;
}
```